# Property of inverse function

Tags: functions

If a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one and bounded is it true that $f^{-1}$ is also one-to-one and bounded? I believe the answer is no but I'm not sure.

Comment: The inverse is one-to-one (otherwise, $f$ wouldn't be a function).

Comment: Technically, a bounded function from R to R can't have inverse

Comment: I think that $ f^{-1} $ here is defined as $ f^{-1} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ (b,a) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} ~|~ (a,b) \in f \} $. Therefore, $ \text{Dom}(f^{-1}) = \text{Range}(f) $ and $ \text{Range}(f^{-1}) = \text{Dom}(f) $.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is always false. The range of $f^{-1}$ is the domain of $f$, which from the way the problem is stated is $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 5):

A counter example: [Logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider $\arctan x$ which is bounded, but $\tan \theta$ isn't bounded.

Comment: +1. Interesting to note that both of us had similar kind of sketch of the function in our mind.

Comment: @Marvis Seems the easiest to use. I wanted a 'simple' example, though OP should have seen Logistic functions under exponentials too. Just wondering, are you an analyst? Your 'calculus/analysis' proofs are very beautiful.

Comment: Thanks and the answer to your question is "I don't know" :-). I am a doctoral student in computational mathematics working in numerical linear algebra/ algorithms. I just dabble in different areas of math with courses I have taken.

Comment: And brilliant.org looks like a great initiative! Good one. Is there a way I can contribute to it?

Comment: @Marvis Thanks! Certainly, we're constantly looking for good problems for students to work on, in which they can demonstrate their problem solving ability. We haven't expanded into calculus/analysis as yet, though we plan to do so in the near future :)

Comment: Sure. I am also interested in Olympiad/Putnam type problem solving in general. Anyway, in case you guys plan to expand and need someone to contribute some time down the line, do keep me posted. :-)

Comment: I am interested in opportunities at brilliant. I saw through MathJobs the position of Mathematics Challenge Master but the deadline (2012/11/02) is over. Are you still accepting applications? If so and if you do not mind me emailing you, can you give me your email id. My id is [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~sivaambi/email.jpg). Thanks.

Comment: @Marvis Done. Was about to email you actually :)

Answer (score 0):

Inverse function itself may not exist. For example the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is one to one and bounded. But its inverse $\log\left(\frac{1}{y} -1\right)$ is not defined for all real numbers.